# How to get a char array into a function, while the size of the array is declared in the main

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I'm trying to get a 2 dimensional char array into a function, but here is the problem:
The size of both dimensions are declared in the main with 'const int' arguments and I can't change that part. If i try to compile the program now, the compiler says that the size of the array is not peferekt declared.

I tried to outrun the problem by using pointers and reference operater, but my knowledge in that field is not big enough for that. I also tried giving the program a hint that it will be declared but it didn't work:

```
void test(const int a, const int b, char* array)
{  .......... }
int main()
{
    const int a=2;
    const int b=3;
    char array[a][b];
    ......  
    test(a,b,&array);
}


test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:28:17: error: cannot convert 'char (*)[2][3]' to 'char*' for argument '3' to 'void test(int, int, char*)'
  test(a,b,&array);
```

The point is in a similar way i got a 1 dimensional string array outside of a function, I tried the other way but somthing went wrong:

```
void test(const int a, const int b, char* array)
{.........}
int main()
{
    const int a=2;
    const int b=3;
    char * array = new char [a][b];
    ..........
    test(a,b,*array);
}


test.cpp:20:31: error: cannot convert 'char (*)[3]' to 'char*' in initialization
char * array = new char [a][b];
test.cpp:5:6: note:   initializing argument 3 of 'void test(int, int, char*)'
 void test(const int a, const int b, char* array)
```

Comment: `&array` will have the type `char(*)[2][3]`. Plain `array` will decay to `&array[0]` which have the type `char(*)[3]`. And `*array` is the same as `array[0]`, which will decay to `&array[0][0]` and have the type `char*`. That's when using actual arrays, not pointers.

Comment: As for passing arrays, you can use templates with the array sizes as template arguments, and pass references to the array. Or use `std::array` instead. But if you have strings then use `std::string` instead.

Comment: So to understand this correct (i'm not the best in understanding english) you would say their is no way in using pointers for that right? Or di I just missunderstanded what you sayed.

Comment: It *is* possible to use pointers, but it has to be pointers of the right type. But there's just no need to use pointers, at all. If you use `std::vector` or `std::string` and need to pass the raw data to a C-function, then there's functions of the vector and string classes that allows you to get a pointer to the data. If you don't call C-functions, then there's just no need to use pointers to begin with.

Comment: Just use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution by passing the address of `array[0][0]` to the `test()` function and treating the 2D char array as 1D.

[Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b682bf47e68dd29)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

void test(int a, int b, char* array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    std::cout << std::string_view(array + i * b, b) << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  const int a = 2;
  const int b = 3;
  char array[a][b];
  array[0][0] = 'a';
  array[0][1] = 'a';
  array[0][2] = 'a';
  array[1][0] = 'b';
  array[1][1] = 'b';
  array[1][2] = 'b';
  test(a, b, &array[0][0]);
}
```

Note that the `const` qualifier for `const int a` is not meaningful and can be omitted. See this [TotW page](https://abseil.io/tips/109) for details.

I also want to bring `std::string_view` (since C++17) to your attention if you want to have a read-only view of a char array and use some `std::string` methods on it. [This](https://dev.to/sandordargo/what-are-stringviews-and-why-should-we-use-them-dn9) is a good tutorial on `std::string_view`.

Comment: Looks like my standart compiler dont like string_view, but thats a problem, that i can handle :D

Comment: Have you tried compiling with the option `-std=c++17`?

Comment: Need to update mingw

Comment: Ok i updated it now it finally works, thanks for helping me, its excacly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
void test(const int a, const int b, char (*array)[3])
{
    ...
}
```

this would also work, (if you prefer)

```
void test(const int a, const int b, char array[2][3])
{
    ...
}
```

and this (note no `&`)

```
test(a,b,array);
```

One the other hand if you are expecting to pass a 2D array of any size into a regular function then this is simply impossible in C++ (or C). Use a 2D `std::vector` instead.

Comment: This didn't worked for me:
Sadly the '3' in the main was only an example. In my real Program the '3' stands for the size of a txt document, so i cant know this size until i use the Program or I have to change the Program everytime i change the document, while I create the program for changing the txt document, so it would made the complet program useless.

Comment: @Chriss91 If the size isn't known at compile-time, or otherwise can't be a compile-time constant (as expected by arrays) then use `std::vector`. Like e.g. `std::vector<std::string>` for a dynamic "array" of strings.

Comment: Can i change an char to a vector and back? If not i caaaaaaan use strings, but it would double the size of the program, cause i have to make chars out of them everytime i have them back in a function to work with them and everytime I want to gave them back i must rebuild strings. I actually tried the 2 dimansional array, cause i tried to save place, and hoped their must be a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: @Chriss91 A vector of strings seems the best choice. Don't convert from string to char array, just use strings throughout. Strings are more powerful than char arrays. What reason do you have for wanting to use char arrays?

Comment: The point is, I want to safe informations by using a .txt document and safe with the program informations in it and to make sure my program understand the informations perfect, I just need an 2dimansional array:
1 Dimansion for every line
1 Dimansion for every digit in a line.
 I need that for if arguments.
TBH you are right in the point that I could use a string,
Anyway the point is that I need a 2 Dimansional Array char/string, not known size, cause the size will be the max needed digits in the line in the document and 1 the number of lines and i dont know them bevor I start the program

Comment: @Chriss91 Then a vector of strings seems the best choice, and also the easiest choice (by far).

Answer (score 0):

For current C++ use std::array for your fixed style arrays, which also allow you to get their sizes at runtime. Rationale : reduce the use of (raw) pointers in C++. (As described in the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines))

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// Define compile time constants
static constexpr std::size_t rows_v = 2;
static constexpr std::size_t cols_v = 3;

// In C++ try to avoid "C" style arrays
// std::array may be a bit more typing but you can pass it easily to functions
// AND it will keep track of its sizes (which "C")
// It also allows you to return arrays from functions WITHOUT having to use pointers.

// I make a type alias here
using my_array_t = std::array<std::array<char, cols_v>, rows_v>;


// pass array by reference to avoid copies
// pass by const so that test only can read values (not modify them).
void test(const my_array_t& values)
{
    // you can just get the size in the function
    // by getting it from the array
    std::cout << "The number of rows = " << values.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "The number of columns = " << values[0].size() << "\n";

    // with arrays (and other containers) you can and
    // should use range based for loops when you can.
    for (const auto& row : values)
    {
        for (const auto& value : row)
        {
            std::cout << value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

// To show you can return arrays from functions without pointers
// also do not worry C++ will not make unecessary copy of the 
// returned array 
my_array_t initialize_array()
{
    my_array_t values{ { {'a','b','c'}, {'d','e','f'} } };
    return values;
}


int main()
{
    auto values = initialize_array();
    test(values);

    return 0;
}
```